# Using wireshark to analyze pcap files

Tags: http, wireshark

I have captured a HTTP request and response in n a pcap file by running curl script from my Linux server. After that i opened it through wireshark. When analyzing packets i saw 404 not found. Does it mean the request i am running is non existent? or the request file ****.html is non existent?
Below is the wireshark data--

9   2017-06-08 17:27:04.035288  x.x.x.x  x.x.x.x    HTTP    287 GET /****.htm HTTP/1.1 
12  2017-06-08 17:27:04.036517  x.x.x.x  x.x.x.x    HTTP    73  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found ..

sorry for all the x's and *'s. This is a little confidential..

Comment: Is your question "how do I analyze packet captures", or "what does an HTTP server returning a 404 mean"?

Comment: Actually it was the second scenario. Turns out i was triggering the wrong HTTP request file. Now its all sorted out.Thank you..@CodeCaster